# How to hide other options in the filter using powerBi Embed

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

so I am appling a basic filter in my config object for my report, it's working but the problem is that the rest of the selections are shown in the filter section, so the user can remove the filtered data and get all the data they want, is there a way to disable this and make only the filtered option visible? Or hide the basic filter while its doing its job in the background?

here is the object i am using:

```
            const facilityFilter = {
            $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
            target: {
                table: "HealthFacilities",
                column: "FacilityName"
            },
            operator: "In",
            values: ["Test Facility"],
            filterType: models.FilterType.BasicFilter,
            requireSingleSelection: true
        };
```

Here is a Demonstration Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: [Eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoGa9.png) did you try to hide the filter ? If the filter is hidden, no-one can change it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make this happen (currently) is through applying Row Level Security or similar approaches in your dataset.

If certain table column values should not be available for certain users, these values must be filtered using RLS rules and role assignments.